# Typescript: type with unknown keys

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript, and really enjoying the language so far. I'm a bit stuck with something that's been bothering me for a little while. Here's the issue:

I have an array of strings, and I'm trying to compute their length. It's as simple as:

```
const corpus: string[] = ["a","ab","b","cvf"];

type distances = {
  [key: string]: number[]
};

const getMatrix = (data: string[]) => {
  let inc: number = 1;
  let sent: string = "Sentence_";
  let struct: distances = <distances>{};
  for (let da of data) {
    for (let d of data) {
      struct[`${sent}${inc}`].push(da.length * d.length)
    }
    inc++;
  }
}

getMatrix(corpus);
```

This doesn't work.

The output should be:

```
{
  Sentence_1: [1,2,3,4],  # random values
  Sentence_2: [1,2,3,4],  # random values
  etc..
}
```

What am I doing wrong and why is my predefined `distances` type returning what I just wrote?

The error message reads:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
```

I've been reading a lot of articles on types, such as [this one](https://www.becomebetterprogrammer.com/typescript-objects-with-unknown-keys-and-known-values/) but still can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

Thanks for your time and patience :)

Comment: If you don't get enough engagement here, you might want to remove the example code's dependency on third-party libraries and use only self-contained code where all the declarations are either provided by TS or in the example code itself.  Good luck!

Comment: What kind of error do you receive? My guess is the syntax you used for casting `let struct: jaccard = <jaccard>{};` confilts with something (JSX maybe?) BTW `let struct: jaccard = {};` is legal and you dont need casting at all.

Comment: Thanks Jcalz and Lesiak for responding!

@Jcalz: Will reformat the code block and remove the dependency on Talisman. Good suggestions, thanks.

@Lesiak: the error I'm getting is that `struct` can not be assigned before it's declared.

No worries guys, I'll continue investigating. Really enjoying TypeScript so far. Thanks for your help! :)